# What are the rules in the UK about attaching a GoPro camera to the outside of an aircraft?

Tags: general-aviation, caa-uk-regulations

Is it fully legal to have a GoPro attached to the outside of the aircraft during flight, in the UK? I've heard mixed answers, but I don't want to try it until I've got confirmation.

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/96/can-i-attach-a-camera-to-the-outside-of-my-aircraft

Comment: Great question. I've wondered about this for a while, but @bjb568's referenced answer is a complete answer to this question.

Comment: The discussion is the same in Germany. One party says that attaching a camera to your aircraft is an alteration which render's the aircraft without certification. Another party says it's fine, because it's not permanent. You will however have another issue, which is: What happens when the camera detaches and damages property or pedestrians on the ground? Your insurance will most likely not cover this....

Comment: For those voting to close as duplicate, please note that the other question asks about FAA regulation. This question is specific to the UK where the UK-CAA is the regulating authority. So this is in fact a different question.

Comment: On its way to damaging people and property on the ground, a detaching camera could also wreak havoc on the aircraft itself.

Answer (score 5):

Flyer magazine had an article on this recently. I've not been able to find the full article on their website, but I have found this which at least partially answers your question.

https://www.flyer.co.uk/gopro-camera-mounts-to-be-approved-by-engineer/

From the article, which was published in Feb 2016:

- Mounting a camera is a modification, and requires either inspection from a Part66 licensed aircraft engineer, or via the CAA as a minor modification.
- To approve any installation the engineer will need to complete a maintenance release checklist and complete the aircraft logbook entry.
- If your aircraft is overseen by the British Microlight Aircraft Association or Light Aircraft Association, then their restrictions apply (but it doesn't say what those are).

It also references CAP1369, which is the CAA document covering mounted cameras. I'm including a link to that here.

[CAA CAP1369](http://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP%201369.pdf)

Comment: welcome to aviation.se Please do not post only a link, the page could disappear any time. Instead, write in your answer the part that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Certificate of Airworthiness may be invalidated with an external attachment to the aircraft.  The aircraft operator will need to inquire to the CAA what applies for the type in question.  This is the operators best course of action to get an answer on airworthiness questions.

However it may just require pilot approval, but it depends, there are however precedence in photography fields already pertaining to external fasteners and equipment. But contacting the CAA is the best way to clear this up.